# XSLT DateTime format conversion to YYYY-DD-MMTHH:MI:SS

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, formatdatetime

I want to convert this

`5/21/15 13:47` to `YYYY-DD-MMTHH:MI:SS`

Source format is `d(or)dd/m(or)mm/yy hh:mm`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Hi michael. Edited the question to add only xslt 2.0

Comment: You could for instance use `xsl:analyze-string` to extract the components, then you can construct an `xs:dateTime` value. However you will need to decide first how to convert a two digit year value to a four digit one.

Comment: Edited and used code formatting rather than bold.  Removed fluff sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$in" 
                    regex="(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="'20',
    format-number(number(regex-group(3)), '00'),
    '-',
    format-number(number(regex-group(1)), '00'),
    '-',
    format-number(number(regex-group(2)), '00'),
    'T',
    format-number(number(regex-group(4)), '00'),
    ':',
    format-number(number(regex-group(5)), '00'),
    ':00'"
  separator=""/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: I did say "something like"... I've removed some of the more obvious errors (but still not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Given an example input of:

**XML**

```
<given-date>5/21/15 13:47</given-date>
```

you can use:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="given-date">
    <result>
            <xsl:variable name="dte" select="tokenize(.,'/|\s')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('20', $dte[3], format-number(number($dte[1]), '-00'), format-number(number($dte[2]), '-00'), 'T', $dte[4], ':00')" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>2015-05-21T13:47:00</result>
```

Note that this assumes all your dates are in the years between 2000 and 2099.